# SAXParser implementation with IBM Websphere dependency

Tags: java, xml-parsing, saxparser

I'm trying to get some help from Java experts around S.O. regarding this issue. I came across an old implementation for a XMLParser in a long time project...
This implementation in my point of view is incorrect, or can be improved..
I was wondering if someone could give a pointer on what to do, an opinion would be highly appreciated...

This is a maven project with a pom.xml for dependencys btw...

The problem...

[image]
So basically someone used in the project the class SAXParser directly from the IBM internal JRE...

How can i convert this peace of code to a dependency free from WAS ( Websphere Aplication Server ) ?

```
    public boolean parse(){
    boolean res = false;
    try {
        SAXParser p = new SAXParser(); // Need to replace this for better aproach
        p.setContentHandler(this); // Need to replace this for better aproach
        InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(new StringReader(source));
        if (inputSource != null){
            p.parse(inputSource); // Need to replace this for better aproach
        }
        res = true;
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("public void parse()"+e.getLocalizedMessage());
        res= false;
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return res;
}
```

**UPDATE**

Migration successfull :)

```
...
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;
...
public boolean parse(){
    boolean res = false;
    try {
        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        spf.setNamespaceAware(true);
        javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser saxParser = spf.newSAXParser();

        XMLReader xmlReader = saxParser.getXMLReader();
        xmlReader.setContentHandler(this);

        InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(new StringReader(source));
        if (inputSource != null){
            xmlReader.parse(inputSource);
        }
        res = true;
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("public void parse()"+e.getLocalizedMessage());
        res= false;
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of explicitly constructing a SAXParser implementation you can ask for a javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser from the javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory:

> ```
>    SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
>    spf.setNamespaceAware(true);
>    SAXParser saxParser = spf.newSAXParser();
> ```
>
> These lines of code create a SAXParserFactory instance, as determined by the setting of the javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory system property.

This is from [the Java tutorial for Parsing an XML file using SAX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/parsing.html).

Then you can get the XMLReader from the SAXParser, set the contentHandler, and parse the xml from the InputSource:

```
XMLReader xmlReader = saxParser.getXMLReader();
xmlReader.setContentHandler(new WhateverYouNameYourContentHandler());
xmlReader.parse(inputSource);
```